# Js click picture click drop down

Tags: javascript, slider

I am very new to JS and I would like to create a drop down when an image is clicked on. When it is clicked on the drop down should slide down to show some extra information and should stay down and keep the information displayed, then when another one of these tags are clicked that one that is down should slide back and the new one down.

Could you please tell me how to do this or give me some tutorial to do?

Thanks so much!

Here is an example: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called an accordion.  Here is a fine tutorial I found that uses jQuery:

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/12/colorful-content-accordion-css-jquery/